# Get id of selected values in CAutoComplete in Yii

Tags: php, yii, autocomplete, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am using CAutoComplete to select multiple comma separated values. Now I am able to pass only the selected values, I need to pass the id of selected values also when the form is submitted.
Can you please help me to send the id on submit as an array or comma separated.

In my form I am using:

```
   <?php
        $this->widget('CAutoComplete', array(
                        'model' => $model,
                        'attribute' => 'skills',
                        'url' => array('serviceRequest/Suggest'),
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'htmlOptions' => array('size' => 34),
                    ));
    ?>
```

Controller:

```
   public function actionSuggest()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['q']) && ($keyword = trim($_GET['q'])) !== '')
        {
            $tags = Skills::model()->suggest($keyword);
            if ($tags !== array())
                echo implode("\n", $tags);
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
 public function suggest($keyword,$limit=20)
    {
        $tags=$this->findAll(array(
            'condition'=>'skills LIKE :keyword',
        //  'order'=>'Name',
            'limit'=>$limit,
            'params'=>array(
                ':keyword'=>'%'.strtr($keyword,array('%'=>'\%', '_'=>'\_', '\\'=>'\\\\')).'%',
            ),
        ));
        $names=array();
        foreach($tags as $tag)
            $names[]=$tag->skills;
        return $names;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass any option that the JUI autocomplete widget supports by including an options array:

```
$this->widget('CAutoComplete', array(
    // your other settings here
    'options' => array(
        'select' => new CJavaScriptExpression('function(e, ui) { alert("hi"); }')
    ),
));
```

Read here for more: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAutoComplete